# if $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $H$ is any subgroup of $G$, then $N \cap H \trianglelefteq H$.

Tags: group-theory

Prove that if $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $H$ is any subgroup of $G$, then $N \cap H \trianglelefteq H$.

attemtp: Recall that in general if $H \trianglelefteq G$, then for all $g \in G$ , $gHg^{-1} = H$
Then let $h \in H$ , so $h(N \cap H)h^{-1} = hNh^{-1} \cap hHh^{-1}  = N \cap hHh^{-1} $.

I know $hNh^{-1} = N$ , since $N\trianglelefteq G$. But can I conclude $H =hHh^{-1} $ ? I dont know since I only know $H $ is any subgroup of $G$.

Can someone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that conjugation "distributes" over intersections like that? It may be so, but I'm dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $k\in H$.  Since $h\in H$, $hkh^{-1}\in H$.  Can you get it from here?

Comment: Then, it would look like $hHh^{-1}$ = {$gkg^{-1} | k \in H$} where $hHh^{-1}$  is the conjugate of $H$ by $h$. So $H$ would be called normal if every element of $H$ normalizes $H$, $hHh^{-1} = H$?

Comment: Well every group is a normal subgroup of itself.