# Show if $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $N \cap H$ is normal subgroup of $H$.

Tags: group-theory

Show if $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then  $N \cap H$ is normal subgroup of $H$.

attempt:  Then recall $N \cap H$ is normal if and only if $h(N \cap H) h^{-1} \subset N \cap H$.

Then suppose $j \in (N \cap H)$ and $h \in H$. , so $hjh^{-1} = (h^{-1})^{-1} j(h^{-1}) = k \in (N \cap H),$ for some $k$, then we can solve for $j$ so we get $j = h^{-1}kh \in h^{-1}(N\cap H)h. $

Hence $N \cap H $ is cointained in $h^{-1}(N \cap H)j$ so $N \cap H = h^{-1}(N \cap H)h$. So $N\cap H$ is normal subgroup of $H$.

Can someone please verify this?
My professor said I need to choose an element from one side and show the element is in the other side too. So containment in both sides. My professor said I can't assume $h(N \cap H) h^{-1}  = hNh^{-1} \cap hHh^{-1} = N \cap H.$
Can someone please help me if this is wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why should you have that $hjh^{-1} = k\ \underbrace{\in N \cap H}_{\text{this part}}$ for some $k$? It sort of seems like you're assuming what you'd like to prove, then doing some algebra to make it seemed like you actually proved it.

Comment: I am lost. At the beginning I was trying to do it the way he said I can't do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think $hHh^{-1} = H$ in the first place?

Comment: because H is in the intersection of N , so H would have to be normal?

Comment: Can you explain "H is in the intersection of N"? Because for any set, $N \cap H \subset H.$

Comment: Indeed $hHh^{-1} = H$ for any subgroup $H$ and element $h \in H$, because $H$ is closed under the group operation.

Comment: @Bungo, no that isn't the problem. When I saw that he wrote "$hNh^{-1} \cap hHh^{-1} = N \cap H.$", I knew this wasn't what he had in mind.

Comment: @Nameless: I agree, that "equation" $h(N\cap H)h^{-1} = hNh^{-1} \cap hHh^{-1}$ does not look correct to me without assuming that $N\cap H \lhd H$ a priori.. I'm trying to think of a counterexample.

Comment: Funnily enough, @Bungo, I made a comment that was similar, a few days ago [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445788/if-n-trianglelefteq-g-and-h-is-any-subgroup-of-g-then-n-cap-h-triangle#comment2945063_1445788). I actually thought it was the same OP until I double checked...

Comment: If $G$ is a group and $N,H$ are arbitrary subsets of $G$ and $h$ is an element og $G$, then $h(N\cap H)h^{-1}=hNh^{-1}\cap hHh^{-1}$. Hence this certainly still holds when $N$ is a special subset of $G$, namely a normal subgroup, and $H$ is a special subset of $G$, namely a subgroup, and $h$ is a special element of $G$, namely an element of $h$. -- Moreover, if $B$ is normal, then clearly $hNh^{-1}=N$, and if $H$ is a subgroup and $h\in H$, then clearly $hHh^{-1}=H$.

Comment: OT, but a simpler proof is to just note that $H\cap N$ is the kernel of $G\to G/N$ restricted to $H$ ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's way easier (algebraically) than you're making it out to be, but it's tricky to get into the right mindset.

Given that $N \lhd G$ with $H$ some subgroup of $G$, we'd like to show that $N \cap H \lhd H$.

In other words, we need to show that conjugating anything in $N \cap H$ by something in $H$ lands us back in $N \cap H$.

So, let $j \in N \cap H$, and let $h \in H$. You just need to show that $h^{-1}jh$ is in $H$ and $N$ also (hence in $N \cap H$). Think about it in these terms before reading on. Seriously.

Why should conjugating $j$ by $h$ land us back in $H$?

> Well, because $j \in H$, and $H$ is a subgroup.

Why should conjugating $j$ by $h$ land us back in $N$?

> Well, because $j \in N$ and $N \lhd G$, with $h \in G$; conjugating anything in $N$ by *anything* in $G$ (of which $H$ is a subgroup) lands us back in $N$.

So, we started with $j \in N \cap H$, and we ended up with $h^{-1}jh \in N \cap H$ so we're done. Easy on algebra, but it definitely takes a certain viewpoint. When I first learned algebra, I would have tried to use *way* more equations and junk, for what it's worth.

Comment: By "algebraically" I essentially mean "symbolically." There's a tendency to think it's not math if your argument is less than $90\%$ symbols, and *that's* what I didn't realize at first.

Answer (score 0):

The thing we need to show is that given any $h\in H$, and $x\in N\cap H$, $y:=hxh^{-1}\in N \cap H$.

Clearly $y$ is in $H$ since $h,x,h^{-1}$ are all in $H$.

$y$ is also in $N$ since $N$ is a normal subgroup and hence conjugating $x$ by anything will still remain in $N$.

Thus, $y\in N\cap H$.

Answer (score 0):

To show $N ∩ H $ is normal in $H$ we must show that the conjugate of $N ∩ H$ by an element
of $h$ is $N ∩ H$. So let $h ∈ H$. Then $h(N ∩ H)h
^{−1} = hNh^{−1} ∩ hHh^{−1}$ but
$hNh^{−1} = N$ since $N$ is normal in $G$, and $hHh^{−1} = H$ since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$,
so $g(N ∩ H)g^
{−1} = N ∩ H$, as desired.